# ERROR TypeError: Object(...)(...).database is not a function @AngularFireDatabase

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Following is the error message I got after `ng build --prod` and `firebase serve`

```
    at main.cf82ca0ea1d6996464f9.js:1
    at e.invoke (polyfills.9d3f36249a52eb1aad15.js:1)
    at t.run (polyfills.9d3f36249a52eb1aad15.js:1)
    at t.runOutsideAngular (main.cf82ca0ea1d6996464f9.js:1)
    at new t (main.cf82ca0ea1d6996464f9.js:1)
    at main.cf82ca0ea1d6996464f9.js:1
    at Oi (main.cf82ca0ea1d6996464f9.js:1)
    at Pi (main.cf82ca0ea1d6996464f9.js:1)
    at t.get (main.cf82ca0ea1d6996464f9.js:1)
    at mo (main.cf82ca0ea1d6996464f9.js:1)
```

However, it's totally fine when `ng build` and `firebase serve` without building in production mode.

My environment settings are

```
    "angularfire2": "5.0.0-rc.4",
    "firebase": "^7.0.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.3",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.5.3"
```

My structure is

> **MyComponent < MyService < AngularFireDatabase && AngularFireStorage**

I'm calling services in component, and that service is calling AnAngularFireDatabase & AngularFireStorage for the actual firebase actions.

I read many articles about similar problem, but no solution can be applied to my problem.

Comment: Probably too late but for anyone else with this problem, make sure you are importing AngularFireDatabaseModule. Older tutorials will often not include this module and will have you provide AngularFireDatabase.